# lint4j installation on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

Has anyone had success installing lint4j on Eclipse Juno and having the options show up in the preferences pane?  My installation shows the lint4j entry in the tree view but there are no options available for it.

Eclipse 4.2 64 bit on Mac OSX

Comment: Do you see anything in the Error Log view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr : Check **Update 2** below. I think I might have found the problem.

I have the same setup as you do (OSX Mountain Lion + Eclipse Juno Java EE 64 Bit)

I just tried installing **[lint4j](http://www.jutils.com/eclipse/index.html)** on my spanking new Eclipse Juno (Java EE). Please take a look at **[this](http://youtu.be/Kn3ZzhOpuVw)** screencast to see how it went.

After installing I had no errors in the Error Logs (as in the video) and my Eclipse preferences had a Lint4j preference option (which did not have any options though) :

[image]

I followed the exact same steps for Eclipse Indigo and got the *exact same* results. So looks like the problem may not be with Eclipse (Indigo / Juno) but with the plugin or the OS we are trying this under. I noticed that the official snapshot too has a the 'missing' options :

[image]

**Update**

This, from **[here](http://www.jutils.com/download.html)**, seems ominous :(

> Lint4j has been developed and tested extensively on MacOSX 10.2 and
>   10.3

And we are trying it out on OSX 10.6 or 10.7 and 10.8 !!

I have just registered to their mailing list (mailto:majordomo@jutils.com), will put up a question there regarding this. Hope we are not missing something obvious from Lint4j's documentation.

**Update 2**

Ah mate, ***I think I found the problem***. We are looking in the wrong place !! I realized this after going through the lint4j intro **[here](http://www.jutils.com/eclipse/intro.html)**.

There are no options to configure in Eclipse preferences. All the lint4j options are available on the project. So if you go into a Java project's properties, there you see the Lint4j preference and the expected options like so :

[image]

Comment: Wow you are right that's exactly where they are - thanks so much. I can't believe I missed that.